# Occurrence of words with same length

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

My function takes a string as input that is the name of a file and should return a dictionary. The dictionary will have key/value pairs where keys are integers that correspond to word lengths and the values are the number of words that appear in the file with that length.

The file consists of the following sentence:

```
and then the last assignment ended and everyone was sad
```

So theoretically the returned diction would look like this:

```
{ 3:5, 4:2, 5:1, 8:1, 10:1}
```

So far I have this:

```
"""
COMP 1005 - Fall 2016
Assignment 10
Problem 1
"""
def wordLengthStats(filename):
    file = open(filename, 'r')
    wordcount={}
    for line in file.read().split():
        if line not in wordcount:
            wordcount[line] = 1
        else:
            wordcount[line] += 1
    for k,v in wordcount.items():
        print (k, v)
    return None

def main():
    '''
    main method to test your wordLengthStats method
    '''
    d = wordLengthStats("sample.txt")
    print("d should be { 3:5, 4:2, 5:1, 8:1, 10:1} ")
    print("d is", d)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The sentence is just an example, I need to make it so that any input should work. Any help on approaching this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `if line not in wordcount:` -- do you intend `if len(line) not in wordcount:`? The keys are supposed to be word *lengths*, not words.

Comment: So what's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every word in the sentence, you need to add an entry to the dictionary where the length of the word is the key:

```
def wordLengthStats(filename):
    file = open(filename, 'r')
    wordcount={}
    for word in file.read().split():

        key = len(word)

        if key not in wordcount:
            wordcount[key] = 1
        else:
            wordcount[key] += 1

    for k,v in wordcount.items():
        print (k, v)                               
    return None
```

Comment: You don't close the file. You should use a `with` block.